# Scala: create array from iterator over array

Tags: arrays, scala, loops, for-loop, iterator

I have an array, for example:

```
val array: Array[String] = Array["a", "b", "c", "10", "20", "30", "40", "50"]
```

and I want to create a new array containing just the integers called `data`.

I tried something like:

```
val data: Array[Int] = Array[Int](for (i <- range 3 to 7) => array(i))
```

I hope the idea is clear, but of course that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `array.slice(3, 8)`

A good resource for answering questions like this in the future: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#package

Comment: Except that won't be an `Array[Int]`. Map over the result to convert the Strings to Ints